# LaTeX trying to prevent a pagebreak before a section heading

Tags: spacing, page-breaking

I have a weird issue.  It seems that LaTeX is trying to prevent a pagebreak before a section heading.

Typesetting a large document with multiple `\chapter`s, `\section`s, and `\subsection`s.  Somewhere in the middle of chapter 7, I'm starting to have a weird issue: I am getting pagebreaks exactly two lines before a `\section` heading while leaving a huge whitespace on the bottom of the previous page (the document is `\raggedbottom`).  At the same time, the space after the two widowed lines before the section heading is smushed together.

And this happens at all subsequent `\section` and `\subsection` headings (quite a few of them happen close enough to possible pagebreaks, where LaTeX, instead of starting them on a new page, produces a huge whitespace before while pulling the last two lines to the next page that has the `\section`.

My hunch is has to do with a couple of included graphics.  There are quite a few included as separate `.tex` files, each looking like this

```
\begin{figure} % No placement specifiers used, so that can't be the problem.
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.6\textwidth]{graphicsfilename}
\caption{Caption}\label{graphicsfilename}
\end{figure}
```

and each being included via `\input{texfilename}`.  However, I'm not forcing any placement, nor are the graphics overly big (all less than a third of a page), and there are also less than one graphics input per page. So it really shouldn't have any problem.

I then tried to force a pagebreak with `\newpage` right before the first problematic `\section` command. That obviously resolved it here, however, the spacing of the remainder of the chapter is now completely off, with either too much or too little whitespace before `\sections` and `\subsections`.

I'm going to try to construct an MWE, however, it might take me a bit to make the issue be reliably reproducible.

So in the meantime, maybe someone has an idea what could be wrong and could point me in a direction where to look for the problem?

Comment: what is after the section head?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle A `\label` and then text ...

Comment: @jan Are you using `listings`?

Comment: @egreg No, unless it's loaded by some other package, but I'm not typesetting any code, so would be surprised.